# How can I format boolean operators with perltidy?

Tags: perl, perl-tidy

To my knowledge, `perltidy` is extremely handy and helpful when it comes to code formatting. However, I haven't found a way to fine-tune `perltidy`. For example, I need the `&&` and `||` formatted so that there are two spaces before and after them. Like this:

`$some  &&  $x > 7;`

Can I do it? If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy enough to rig up your own tidy script with [`PPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI) that you can run after `perltidy`. Proof-of-concept:

```
use PPI;
my $doc = PPI::Document->new($ARGV[0]);
for my $op (@{$doc->find('PPI::Token::Operator')}) {
    if ($op eq '&&' || $op eq '||') {
        $op->{content} = " $op ";
    }
}
print $doc;
```

And if we run this script on itself, we get:

```
$ perl je8tidy.pl je8tidy.pl
use PPI;
my $doc = PPI::Document->new($ARGV[0]);
for my $op (@{$doc->find('PPI::Token::Operator')}) {
    if ($op eq '&&'  ||  $op eq '||') {
        $op->{content} = " $op ";
    }
}
print $doc;
```

It did insert the extra spaces around the only `||` operator on line 4.

Answer (score 3):

[perltidy](https://metacpan.org/dist/Perl-Tidy/view/bin/perltidy) does not have an option to add two spaces before and after operators.

Furthermore, if you manually add 2 spaces, then run `perltidy`, it will convert the 2 spaces to a single space by default.  However, there are options for [skipping selected lines of code](https://metacpan.org/dist/Perl-Tidy/view/bin/perltidy#Skipping-Selected-Sections-of-Code).