# Is it possible to make perltidy plugin?

Tags: perl, perl-tidy

Referring to my previous question: [How can I format boolean operators with perltidy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73511956/how-can-i-format-boolean-operators-with-perltidy) wondering if it's possible to make a `perltidy` plugin with my own finer formatting rules? Does `perltidy` allow this?

Comment: Go to their [github page](https://github.com/perltidy/perltidy) and create your own fork.

Comment: Perl::Tidy allows for pre-filters and post-filters: 
 https://metacpan.org/release/SHANCOCK/Perl-Tidy-20220613/source/examples/filter_example.pl . That should get you pretty close.